# Lambda expression to create Table-result

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of data that I want to display as a table in a GUI (HTML).

I want to create a lambda expression so that a list of hundred items is for instance divided into 20 rows, 5 items each. Can I create a concise lambda expression to do this?

This is what I came up with (yes, 5 is a magic number, it is the number of items per row):

```
bool isCreateNewRow = true;

var aggregate = Model.Aggregate(new Collection<ICollection<Album>>(), 
                (tableCollection, album) =>
                  {
                      if (isCreateNewRow)
                      {
                          tableCollection.Add(new Collection<Album>());
                          isCreateNewRow = false;
                      }
                      tableCollection.Last().Add(album);
                      if(tableCollection.Last().Count() >= 5)
                      {
                          isCreateNewRow = true;
                      }
                      return tableCollection;
                  });
```

Is there a shorter way to create a 2 dimensional datastructure (IEnumerables of IEnumerables)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create 20 dummy items.
var albums = Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
    .Select(i => string.Format("Album {0}", i));

// Associate each one with the row index.
var numbered = albums
    .Select((item, index) =>
        new { Row = index / 3, Item = item });

// Arrange into rows.
var table = numbered
    .GroupBy(x => x.Row)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x=>x.Item).AsEnumerable());
```

At this point, `table` is an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`.

To turn it into HTML, try this:

```
var html = rows.Aggregate(
    new StringBuilder("<table>"),
    (tableBuilder, row) => {
        tableBuilder.AppendFormat("<tr>{0}</tr>",
            row.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
            (rowBuilder, cell) => {
                rowBuilder.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", cell);
                return rowBuilder;
            }));
        return tableBuilder;
    },
    (tableBuilder) => {
        tableBuilder.Append("</table>");
        return tableBuilder;
    });
```

Comment: ...but I agree with Henk. It is possible to get a bit *too* clever with LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

It would be so much easier to

a) create your (1D) resultset
 b) use 1 or 2 `for` loops to process (present) those results in table form.

Also because those 2 steps would logically belong to different layers of a solution.

Comment: +1 for thinking about the most simple solution. LINQ is nice but the habit to express everything in LINQ makes the code much more difficult to read when the people do use LINQ only for the sake of using it and then mostly in a clumsy way.